# open source language recognition library?

Tags: php, javascript, c++, c, text

I'm searching for a lib which can recognize the human language of a .txt document
I already found [this page](http://www.google.com/uds/samples/language/detect.html)
but im more interested in source code which I can use offline
some language which would be great to support
english, french, german

programming language which would be best
c/c++, php, JS is also ok

Any hints for libs or just how I could better search on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a this library: http://software.wise-guys.nl/libtextcat/

Answer (score 0):

i just found [this](http://github.com/feedbackmine/language_detector) which seems simple to convert to php code

Answer (score 0):

For JS I would recommend [franc](https://github.com/wooorm/franc).
If you consider also Rust as an option, I can recommend [whatlang](https://github.com/greyblake/whatlang-rs).